# How to use "Stanford Parser" and get triple

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I want to use standford parser to extract object，subject，predicate from a complex sentence，but there are different subject like dobj,iobj,nsubjpass,I do not konwn how to write code using java.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `openie` annotator.

```
java -Xmx14g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,depparse,natlog,openie -file sample-sentence.txt -outputFormat text
```

Comment: I do not want to use StanfordCoreNLP,but "Stanford Parser".